# C# smtp configuration in system.net.mail

Tags: c#, winforms, smtpclient, mailmessage

I have a small WinForms application that sends notification emails. It works fine with outlook clients but bombs if a gmail/yahoo/windowslive address is entered. I've seen many posts using system.web.mail and schemas but Visual Studio 2010 gives me an error when trying to use this (I'm assuming because of .Net 2.0). Is it possible to configure my smtp client code to relay to all of these email providers?

Im using system.net.mail with MailMessage. My configuration code is below...

```
SmtpClient mailSender = new SmtpClient("smtp.myclient.com");
            mailSender.EnableSsl = true;
            mailSender.Send(message);
```

Comment: Smtp can work over different ports in different configurations, and often it needs to have authentication. Each will potentially work differently, which is why most apps have configurable Smtp settings.

Comment: Are you refering to setting the smtp settings in the app.config file? I have seen some documentation on MSDN about this. Would you think this would help?

Comment: Smtp settings can be defined in code using the SmtpClient API. Have a look at the documentation and check out the host, port, and credentials properties.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine for Outlook clients because the workstation is (likely) logged into the Active Directory Domain and the Exchange server "trusts" the connection because of it.

You need to add the user's credentials on the mail service, and you'll have to get them from the user:

```
 mailsender.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

Also, don't forget to set the Port property for SSL.  Some providers don't use the standard ones.

Comment: Ok, I know this is a stupid question and I hope I dont get bashed BUT what user are you refering to that I need credentials from?

Comment: Not a stupid question.  The user who is sending the email.  You have to have a valid account to send "From."  Back in the wild west days of the Internet, you could just find the mailserver for the domain of the recipient's address and send an unauthenticated message (as above) to that one.  Many Exchange servers still allow that from "internal" IP addresses.  However, most mail servers will not relay a message from an unauthenticated user, and most will not accept messages even to an account on that server from an external address, these days.

Answer (score 0):

If your application works with outlook clients then you application sends email correctly. The only difference with web address is the way the emails are shown so maybe the problem is with the encoding. Can you detail what means that the application bombs?

Comment: yes i get a Mailbox unavailable 5.7.1 unable to relay error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an exception message even if your credentials supplied to the mail servers would be OK by themselves, but the "From" field doesn't match that particular user. (This is a feature, a restriction enforced by the SMTP servers to prevent spoofing a sender. The SMTP protocol itself is so liberal, that in theory you can write any e-mail address into the "From" field. Preventing spoofing is very important to fight against e-mail spam.)

In general if you do something wrong, you'll receive an SmtpException, which is unexpectedly descriptive. Sometimes the embedded inner exception distinguish more cases. You just have to debug the various cases, I sorted out some:

1. If the "from" address of the e-mail doesn't match the e-mail address of the authenticated user what he/she is entitled to, you'll get an SmtpException saying "Mailbox unavailable." and "Client does not have permissions to send as this sender".
2. If you specify a wrong host or port, the SmtpException message will start with "Mailbox unavailable.", it'll have an inner exception of type WebException saying "Unable to connect to the remote server", which will have an inner exception itself of a type SocketException, saying "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".
3. If you turn on SSL (mailSender.EnableSsl = true; // for your code), but the SMTP server doesn't support it, or the other way around, then you'll get an SmtpException saying "Server does not support secure connections".
4. If the credentials (username/password) are wrong or some other SSL problem cases you'll get an SmtpExeption saying "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated".

Another thing to pay attention is how exactly you create your NetworkCredential object.

System.Net.Mail is very convenient!